# Go Tour flowcontrol #5: understand the return keyword

Tags: go

In the [slide #5](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/5) of the flow control Go Tour I don't understand how the `return` keyword is working inside the function `sqrt()`.

```
func sqrt(x float64) string {
    if x < 0 {
        return sqrt(-x) + "i"
    }
    return fmt.Sprint(math.Sqrt(x))
}
```

I understand the code with a `else` clause like this

```
func sqrt(x float64) string {
    if x < 0 {
        return sqrt(-x) + "i"
    }else{
        return fmt.Sprint(math.Sqrt(x))
    }
}
```

This code executes without problems, but the linter, golint, in VsCode complains about the `else` clause.

Does the statement `return sqrt(-x) + "i"` inside the first `if` block ends the execution of the function ?

how is it exactly working ?

Answer (score 1):

As with most (if not all?) the first return statement the compiler hits will exit the function and not continue.

Answer (score 0):

It's warning reported by go linter. Code underneath is valid.

```
func sqrt(x float64) string {
    if x < 0 {
        return sqrt(-x) + "i"
    }

    return fmt.Sprint(math.Sqrt(x))
}
```

This one below is also valid, but will generate some warning.

```
func sqrt(x float64) string {
    if x < 0 {
        return sqrt(-x) + "i"
    } else {
        return fmt.Sprint(math.Sqrt(x))
    }
}
```

Basically if there is `if` statement and the body contains `return` statement, better not to use `else` block.